# How do I deal with monthly time series data of 3900+ regions at once

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am working on a time series model and I am new to this. I have just started learning time series analysis and forecasting.
I know how to deal with monthly data.
But I have a bigger and huge data that I need to solve.
It has monthly time series data for 3900+ regions.
I want to predict the values for next 12 months using R.
My data looks something like this : https://drive.google.com/file/d/10QvtS55NQ1kIXxeccWxXl0SqqyqYXyoh/view?usp=sharing

I know how to do this for 1 region using ARIMA model but don't know how to handle this big data.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question itself does not contain all the necessary details, but links are shared instead. Over time links will be broken and this question will become unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

as you are new to the topic, I recommend you to take a look at the approach of using global models like xgboost or glmnet instead.

You will fail to produce scalable results with the "forecast" package or similar local time series approaches using ARIMA, ETS, Prophet and so on.

When your models are complex enough to produce accurate forecasts, they will take a lot of time to compute.  For example a model prediction with fully tuned local models took about 5 hours for 100 time series (5 years of train, one year of test) to complete. With global models it is a matter of just 3 minutes.

As I am using it myself, I may recommend the modeltime framework which makes use of the tidymodels stack.

Comment: Nice answer, but could use a few line breaks into separate paragraphs...a large blob of text like this with no lines between can be hard to read.

Comment: just edited my answer as you proposed. If the answer is helpful or solved your problem, please indicate this by accepting it or marking it as useful